# Reflection vs. Compile To Get The Value Of MemberExpression

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

How can I achieve this without using Compile() but just with normal reflection?

```
var value = Expression.Lambda(memberExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

I want this to be able to run on an IPhone (MonoTouch), which does not allow dynamic compiling.

UPDATE: Here is more context.  This is the code I am working on:

```
if (expression.Expression is ConstantExpression)
{
 var constantExpression = (ConstantExpression)expression.Expression;
 var fieldInfo = constantExpression.Value.GetType().GetField(expression.Member.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
 if (fieldInfo != null)
 {
  return fieldInfo.GetValue(constantExpression.Value);
 }
 {
  var propertyInfo = constantExpression.Value.GetType().GetProperty(expression.Member.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
  if (propertyInfo != null)
  {
   return propertyInfo.GetValue(constantExpression.Value, null);
  }
 }
}
else
{
 return Expression.Lambda(expression.Expression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
}
```

As you can see, the code in the if block uses no runtime compilation to obtain the value.  My goal is that the code in the in the else block **not** use runtime compilation either.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.  Reflection is tool for metadata and **very** limited byte code inspection.  It does not allow for mutation or code generation.  Fundamentally what you are trying to achieve here is a metadata and IL generation act.  Reflection will not work for this scenario.

Comment: What you say is not totally correct.  I know, for example, that in the case that memberExpression.Expression is a ConstantExpression you can get its value by reflecting on the constant expression's Value property.  My problem is that when it's not a ConstantExpression, I cannot figure how to get a handle on the instance that holds the value.

Comment: If it's not a constant, you will need to execute it to get the result. Thus the compile.

Answer (score 0):

I have some more specific cases:

```
    private static object ExtractValue(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var ce = expression as ConstantExpression;
        if (ce != null)
        {
            return ce.Value;
        }

        var ma = expression as MemberExpression;
        if (ma != null)
        {
            var se = ma.Expression;
            object val = null;
            if (se != null)
            {
                val = ExtractValue(se);
            }

            var fi = ma.Member as FieldInfo;
            if (fi != null)
            {
                return fi.GetValue(val);
            }
            else
            {
                var pi = ma.Member as PropertyInfo;
                if (pi != null)
                {
                    return pi.GetValue(val);
                }
            }
        }

        var mce = expression as MethodCallExpression;
        if (mce != null)
        {
            return mce.Method.Invoke(ExtractValue(mce.Object), mce.Arguments.Select(ExtractValue).ToArray());
        }

        var le = expression as LambdaExpression;
        if (le != null)
        {
            if (le.Parameters.Count == 0)
            {
                return ExtractValue(le.Body);
            }
            else
            {
                return le.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
            }
        }

        var dynamicInvoke = Expression.Lambda(expression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        return dynamicInvoke;
    }
```

May be there are library with more complex expressions (new object creations etc.).